Tikz: can't use macro to store coordinate Y in \draw X to Y
I need to store the coordinate of a point (computed via some non-trivial operations from the calc library) in a macro, and draw a line to this point later. I can do it without any issue if the point is a starting point but it fails if the point is an ending point.
Any idea how to solve this?
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
% In the end, \foo will look like some calculation of points like
% \def\foo{($(txt.south west) + ##1*(txt.south east) - ##1*(txt.south west) + ##2*(txt.north east) - ##2*(txt.south east)$)}%
\def\foo{(annot)} 
\def\bar{(txt)} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[name=annot] at (0,0) {A};
  \node[name=txt] at (0,3) {B};
  % Works:
  \draw \foo to[bend right] (txt);
  % Fails:
  \draw \foo to[bend left] \bar;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

EDIT:
Seems like doing:
  \expanded{\noexpand\draw \noexpand\foo to[bend left] \bar;}

instead of the above \draw works! Is this the recommended approach?
EDIT2
So the reason I'm interested in this is to create an "annotation" package to easily add anotations like:

while providing maximum flexibility to change later the starting/ending points, the shape of the arrow (straight, bending, bezier…) etc.
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  annotation/.style={
    font=\tiny,
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    fill={red!10!white},
    inner sep=3pt
  },
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\annot}{D<>{1-}O{}mm}{%
  \def\annotStyleAnnot{annotation}%
  \def\annotStyleAnnotExtra{}%
  \def\annotStyleTxt{}%
  \def\annotPositionAnnot{}%
  \def\annotStartingPoint{(annot)}%
  \def\annotEndingPoint{(txt)}%
  \def\annotStyleArrow{-latex}%
  \def\annotStyleTo{.. controls (annot.center -| txt.center) ..}%
  {%
    \pgfkeys{%
      /myAnnot/.cd,
      style to/.code={\def\annotStyleTo{##1}},
      straight/.style={
        style to={--}
      },
      style annot/.code={\def\annotStyleAnnotExtra{##1}},
      style annot orig/.code={\def\annotStyleAnnot{##1}},
      style txt/.code={\def\annotStyleTxt{##1}},
      pos annot/.code={\def\annotPositionAnnot{##1}},
      C/.code={%
        \def\annotPositionAnnot{anchor=center,at=(txt.center),shift={(0,0)}}%
      },
      N/.style={%
        /utils/exec={\def\annotPositionAnnot{anchor=south,at=(txt.north),shift={(0,\annotDistance)}}},
        distance=4mm,
        straight,
      },
      S/.style={%
        /utils/exec={\def\annotPositionAnnot{anchor=north,at=(txt.south),shift={(0,-\annotDistance)}}},%
        distance=4mm,
        straight,
      },
      E/.style={%
        /utils/exec={\def\annotPositionAnnot{anchor=west,at=(txt.east),shift={(\annotDistance,0)}}},%
        distance=4mm,
        straight,
      },
      W/.style={%
        /utils/exec={\def\annotPositionAnnot{anchor=east,at=(txt.west),shift={(-\annotDistance,0)}}},%
        distance=4mm,
        straight,
      },
      NE/.code={%
        \def\annotPositionAnnot{anchor=south west,at=(txt.north east),shift={(\annotDistance,\annotDistance)}}%
      },
      NW/.code={%
        \def\annotPositionAnnot{anchor=south east,at=(txt.north west),shift={(-\annotDistance,\annotDistance)}}%
      },
      SE/.code={%
        \def\annotPositionAnnot{anchor=north west,at=(txt.south east),shift={(\annotDistance,-\annotDistance)}}%
      },
      SW/.code={%
        \def\annotPositionAnnot{anchor=north east,at=(txt.south west),shift={(-\annotDistance,-\annotDistance)}}%
      },%
      NW,
      distance/.code={%
        \def\annotDistance{##1}%
      },
      distance=2mm,
      % shift={(-1mm,1mm)}
      shift/.code={%
        \def\annotShiftStyle{shift={##1}}%
      },
      shift={(0,0)},
      % spc is for "start percent", use like spc={1}{.8}, where (0,0) is the lower left, (1,1) is upper right, and (x,y) is percent x/percent y.
      spc/.code 2 args={%
        \def\annotStartingPoint{($(annot.south west) + ##1*(annot.south east) - ##1*(annot.south west) + ##2*(annot.north east) - ##2*(annot.south east)$)}%
      },
      % se is for "start east"
      sn/.code={\def\annotStartingPoint{(annot.north)}},
      ss/.code={\def\annotStartingPoint{(annot.south)}},
      se/.code={\def\annotStartingPoint{(annot.east)}},
      sw/.code={\def\annotStartingPoint{(annot.west)}},
      sne/.code={\def\annotStartingPoint{(annot.north east)}},
      snw/.code={\def\annotStartingPoint{(annot.north west)}},
      sse/.code={\def\annotStartingPoint{(annot.south east)}},
      ssw/.code={\def\annotStartingPoint{(annot.south west)}},
      % epc is for "end percent", use like spc={1}{.8}, where (0,0) is the lower left, (1,1) is upper right, and (x,y) is percent x/percent y.
      epc/.code 2 args={%
        \def\annotEndingPoint{($(txt.south west) + ##1*(txt.south east) - ##1*(txt.south west) + ##2*(txt.north east) - ##2*(txt.south east)$)}%
      },
      % se is for "start east"
      en/.code={\def\annotEndingPoint{(txt.north)}},
      es/.code={\def\annotEndingPoint{(txt.south)}},
      ee/.code={\def\annotEndingPoint{(txt.east)}},
      ew/.code={\def\annotEndingPoint{(txt.west)}},
      ene/.code={\def\annotEndingPoint{(txt.north east)}},
      enw/.code={\def\annotEndingPoint{(txt.north west)}},
      ese/.code={\def\annotEndingPoint{(txt.south east)}},
      esw/.code={\def\annotEndingPoint{(txt.south west)}},
      style arrow/.code={\def\annotStyleArrow{##1}},
      #2
    }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(txt.base)]%
      \node[name=txt,inner sep=0pt,style/.expand once=\annotStyleTxt]{#3};
      \only<#1>{
        \node[name=annot,overlay,
        style/.expand once=\annotPositionAnnot,
        style/.expand once=\annotShiftStyle,
        style/.expand once=\annotStyleAnnot,
        style/.expand once=\annotStyleAnnotExtra,
        draw
        ]{#4};
        \expanded{\noexpand\draw[overlay,style/.expanded=\annotStyleArrow] \annotStartingPoint
          % to[style/.expanded=\annotStyleTo]
          % to[out=0,in=90]
          \annotStyleTo
          \annotEndingPoint;}
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
  Encryption $c \gets \mathsf{Enc}(k, \annot[SW]{$m$}{Message $m \in \mathcal{M}$})$
\end{frame}

\end{document}


It's not clear why you want to do it this way. Why can't you use \draw (annot) to[bend right] (txt);?  If you want calculated coordinates use something like\coordinate[...](<myname>) at (<coordinate calc>); (or something with \path). But it's unlikely that you need to do the calculation in \def.

not the recommended approach, no. using \def at the top-level of your document isn't recommended, but this also isn't really the way calc is designed to work. think in terms of coordinates and pics rather than macros ;).

I suspect the TikZ parser is looking for the surrounding parenthesis before the LaTeX parser expands the macro.  After is too late.  Something similar occurs when you put & inside a macro and try to use it in a tabular.  Solution is: don't do that.

An example of the “ultimate” version is needed.

Thanks all. So I added an example of the ultimate version as requested to show why I need a flexible system here.

This is a very long code for a very small thing. I doubt that this is necessary and also that anyone will analyze this long code. If you do this with tikzmark, the output shown in the image should take a few  lines.

@cis As in most packages, the interest of writing a long code comes when we call it really often (which is my case). I don't want to lose like 5 lines every time I want to annotate something in a presentation, and copy/pasting tikzmark-based code harms both readability, efficiency and coherence across the document. Regarding the fact that no-one will read my code, that's the reason why I published a MWE, but people asked me to publish the "ultimate" version… so here we go ;-)

\draw \foo \expanded{to[bend left] \bar}; should be enough. See #1534. Try to have \bar be just the node name excluding the () then you can have to[bend left] (\bar) without a problem.

All this \deffing goes against what PGFKeys can offer you. Take a look at A667222 where just a few simple styles can already give six positions for the annotation. (Using \underset/\overset in combination with trim left and trim right makes sure that vertical space is reserved for the annotation but no horizontal space.)

@Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. I thought that I tried the to[bend left] (\bar) without success… but seems it works actually. But this is still not enough if also want to have the to configurable, for instance to have a bezier etc. Your example is nice, but still not as configurable. I also want to be able to configure the distance etc, so it's hard for me to do it without \def or the (certainly more pgf-styled) .store in… But cool idea!

The (\bar) solution will still make troubles with [] options at the start or $ for the calc library's syntax. Maybe something for #1091.
In the code below, both coordinates are \expanded (along with the to path operation and its options).
Another approach would be
\annotset{
    txt     anchor/.style={if empty={#1}{@check   txt/.code=}{@check   txt/.code=\edef\tikztostart{\tikztostart.#1}}},
  annot     anchor/.style={if empty={#1}{@check annot/.code=}{@check annot/.code=\edef\tikztotarget{\tikztotarget.#1}}},
    txt percentage/.style={if empty={#1}{@check   txt/.code=}{@check   txt/.style={@check percentage={{\tikztostart}#1}}}},
  annot percentage/.style={if empty={#1}{@check annot/.code=}{@check annot/.style={@check percentage={{\tikztotarget}#1}}}},
  @check percentage/.code args={#1#2:#3}{\edef#1{[shift=(#1.south west), x=(#1.south east), y=(#1.north west)]{#2},{#3}}},
  @check txt/.code=, @check annot/.code=,
  @beforeto/.style={execute at begin to=\annotset{@check txt, @check annot, /tikz/insert path=(\tikztostart)}},
}

with the path being
[/annot/@beforeto] (txt) to[/annot/@topath, /annot/every to] (annot)

The insert path is needed because just changing \tikztostart doesn't change the path magically, the “pen” is still at (txt) when the to path with the corrected \tikztostart is executed.
It is a more TikZ-y approach since it does the work as part of the to operation instead of beforehand but since you package this inside the \annot macro it might be more complicated than is necessary.
In my opinion, \expanded is safe to use here as there's no nonexpandable, i.e. fragile, commands inside \expanded's argument (like node text).
I could also see a combination of both: \annotstart will be determined as below and \tikztotarget will be changed as above (after (annot) is parsed but before the to path is executed).

I've commented a bit in the code below, but in short:

Each of txt, annot, path and to has an every style and a pluralized key that appends to the every style. This is similar to how /tikz/nodes appends to /tikz/every node which I find to be a good unwritten rule.

@topath is an internal key that is set by the shortcuts that is used to give each shortcut a default to path but still allows the user to overwrite it.

The outer sep of the txt node is set to zero while the arrow tip includes a sep of .3333em now. This basically implement asymmetrical seps (the arrow tip shouln't be too close to the text). However, this messes up the percentange anchor … though maybe it isn't about precision but about fine-tuning?

I've implemented the results of Spacing: tikz drawing like a math relation

I'm also using \mathpalette to use the appropriate math style in the txt node, it is used \string-ified as a key which allows to change things according to the math style.

AMSMath's \text macro has a neat functionality because it sets up fontsizes that follows the current math style, this would replace the \mathpalette from the previous point but since you already hard-code \tiny for the annot node, it's not as useful here. Nonetheless, \annotX uses it. You may see that lengths with units em and ex are scaled properly.

rounded corners aren't visible to the arrow tip drawing algorithms which is why I'm using a proper curve for the SSW style.


Code
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, bending}
\newcommand*\annotset{\pgfqkeys{/annot}}
\makeatletter
\annotset{if empty/.code n args={3}{\edef\@temp{#1}\ifx\@temp\@empty\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi{#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{vh/.style={to path=|-(\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes}}
\annotset{
  .code=\annotset{#1}, % this allows /annot={<key-value list>} where the argument is executed in the /annot path
  Annot Tip/.tip={Latex[round]},
  x distance/.initial=.5em, y distance/.initial=.5em, % I differentiate between both distances
  distance/.style={x distance={#1}, y distance={#1}}, % but provide a key to set both
  % I provide an “every” key for each part: the main node, the annotation node, the path and also the to …
  every txt node/.style={inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=auto, path only, alias=txt},
  every annot node/.style={font=\tiny, draw, rounded corners, fill=red!10, inner sep=+3pt, text depth=+0pt, alias=annot},
  every to/.code=,
  every path/.style={arrows={Annot Tip[sep=+.3333em]-}, rounded corners, draw},
  % … as well as appenders:
    txts/.style={/annot/every   txt node/.append style={#1}},
  annots/.style={/annot/every annot node/.append style={#1}},
     tos/.style={/annot/every         to/.append style={#1}},
   paths/.style={/annot/every       path/.append style={#1}},
  % keys that set the anchors (for the connection), empty argment for no anchor
    txt anchor/.style={if empty={#1}{\def\annottxt{txt}}{\def\annottxt{txt.#1}}},
  annot anchor/.style={if empty={#1}{\def\annotannot{annot}}{\def\annotannot{annot.#1}}},
  txt anchor=, annot anchor=, % initializing
  % keys that use the special percentage anchor, empty argument as above
    txt percentage/.style={if empty={#1}{\def\annottxt{txt}}{\annotset{@check percentage={{txt}#1}}}},
  annot percentage/.style={if empty={#1}{\def\annotannot{annot}}{\annotset{@check percentage={annot}#1}}},
  @check percentage/.code args={#1#2:#3}{\expandafter\def\csname annot#1\endcsname{[shift={(#1.south west)}, x=(#1.south east), y=(#1.north west)]{#2},{#3}}},
  % maybe something for different math styles (for \annot, not \annotX)
  @math/\string\scriptstyle/.style={every annot node/.append style={scale=.75, rounded corners=+3pt}},
  % a useful key that is used below to setup the shortcuts
  @@placing/.style n args={5}{
    @topath/.style={#1},
    @placement/.style={at=(txt.#2), anchor=#3, xshift=#4(\pgfkeysvalueof{/annot/x distance}), yshift=#5(\pgfkeysvalueof{/annot/y distance})}},
  % these seem helpful
  no trim/.code=\pgfsettrimleft{default}\pgfsettrimright{default},
     trim/.code=\pgfsettrimleftpointlater{\pgfpointanchor{txt}{west}}\pgfsettrimrightpointlater{\pgfpointanchor{txt}{east}}, % untested
  % all the shortcuts
  SW/.style={@@placing={vh}{south west}{north east}{-}{-}},
  SE/.style={@@placing={vh}{south east}{north west}{}{-}},
  NW/.style={@@placing={vh}{north west}{south east}{-}{}},
  NE/.style={@@placing={vh}{north east}{south west}{}{}},
  N/.style={y distance=1em, @@placing={line to}{north}{south}{0*}{}},
  S/.style={y distance=1em, @@placing={line to}{south}{north}{0*}{-}},
  E/.style={x distance=1em, @@placing={line to}{base east}{base west}{}{0*}, txt anchor=mid east, annot anchor=mid west, no trim},
  W/.style={x distance=1em, @@placing={line to}{base west}{base east}{-}{0*}, txt anchor=mid west, annot anchor=mid east, no trim},
  %
  SSW/.style={
    @@placing={controls=(txt|-annot) and (txt|-annot)}{south west}{north east}{-}{-},
    y distance=.1ex, x distance=.5em,
    paths={arrows={Annot Tip[bend, scale=.75, sep=+.1em]-}, rounded corners=+3pt}},
}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\annot}{D<>{1-}O{}mm}{\ifmmode\binrel@{#3}\mathpalette\annot@{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}\else\annot@@{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\fi}
\newcommand*\annot@[2]{\annot@unpack{#1}#2}
\newcommand*\annot@unpack[5]{\binrel@@{\annot@@{#2}{@math/\string#1/.try,#3}{$\m@th#1#4$}{#5}}}
\newcommand*\annot@@[4]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=(txt.west), trim right=(txt.east), baseline=(txt.base), /annot={#2}]
    \node[/annot/every txt node] {#3};
    \path<#1>[/annot/every path]
      node[/annot/every annot node, /annot/@placement]{#4}
      \expanded{(\annottxt) to[/annot/@topath, /annot/every to] (\annotannot)};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
% AMSMath packages provides \text which scales its argument according to the current math style
% this also applies to the font dimensions em and ex which might be useful
\usepackage{amsmath}
\NewDocumentCommand{\annotX}{D<>{1-}O{}mm}{\ifmmode\binrel@{#3}\binrel@@{\text{\annot@@{#1}{#2}{$\m@th#3$}{#4}}}\else\annot@@{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\foreach[count=\i] \dir in {SW, SE, NW, NE, N, S, E, W}{%
  Encryption $c \gets \mathsf{Enc}(k, \annot<\i->[\dir]{m}{Message $m \in \mathcal{M}$})$
  \par
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Some formulas}
\[
  longformula_{\annot[SSW]{i}{Index}} \quad a\annot[NW]{=}{Equal}b
\]
\[
  longformula_{\annotX[SSW]{i}{Index}} \quad a\annotX[NW]{=}{Equal}b
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Output


